# in Excel, Can I replace "sheet1!" with a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 100 sheets named as 1,2,3....100
then in each sheet, there's a value in cell A1.
I am building a summary sheet now, in the summary sheet, I want A1 = 1!A1, A2 = 2!A1, A3 = 3!A1 ...... A100 = 100!A1
I am thinking of replace the "1!" with some sorts of formula but can't do.
How Can I paste the values quickly instead of going into each sheet.

Thanks and hopefully I described it clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use this formula and drag it down -

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet",ROW(),"!$A$1"))
```

It will use the row where it's at to determine the sheet number.

You could also use something like this

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!$A$1")
```

these both use the [INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx)() function, which is volatile.